# Neo4j Java API: Bad Dijkstra performance

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, dijkstra

Using Neo4j's Java API version 3.1.0-M08, I built a shortest path search using the Dijkstra algorithm. I have a lot of data, 28 GB on disk. The nodes represent cities and the relations represent connections. Typically, a city will have a very high number of connections. In my `PathExpander` I exclude a high number of relations which leads to only a tiny fraction of the whole graph being traversed. Nevertheless, the search performs awfully:

```
Relations traversed: 5343
Duration: ~14s
Performance: 373 relations/s
```

This is what profiling hot methods of a warmed up run looks like:

[image]

The `PathExpander` and the `CostEvaluator` read properties of type `Long`, `Integer` and `Double`. I tried replacing calls to `getProperty` with `getAllProperties` which didn't help.

The app is launched with the following JVM arguments: `-Xmx10g -Xms10g`. I have a fairly fast SSD and I make sure to preload the caches before measuring by running the same search a couple of times. Starting with the second run, I see no disk activity, meaning the traversed graph should be in RAM.

I call the `GraphDatabaseFactory` with the default arguments. Could custom configurations improve performance? Note, that I only have 16 GB RAM for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that every city node was connected to a very high amount of connection relations. Even though a lot of the relations were excluded, to exclude them, every one of them had to be read. The solution was to change the model. The new model looks as follows:

```
(:City)-[:ConnectionDay {day: {day}}]->(:ConnectionDay)-[:Connection]->(:City)
```

Because only connections on a particular day can be considered, all the connections on different days are never touched.